# MS CRM Word Document Generation coming with WordTemplateExportRecordId:

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

Recently I am using the Word **Document Generation** feature and I found that my generated Word Document is appending the below part in the end of document and it is very odd.
**WordTemplateExportRecordId: GUID1, GUID2, GUID3..etc.**

If it fetches the info from different entities, it is printing there's guids as I verified.

Before some days it was working perfectly, suddenly I am facing this issue, while generating the old existing document and it contains the GUIDS at the end whereas same document was generating perfectly before, totally annoying.

NOTE: This document is getting generated using [Action : SetWordTemplate]

any idea anyone, please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It was brought to our attention that this is apparently a bug with the Dynamics 365 version `8.2.2.2060`. Our client was updated to this version on 13-Jul-2018 and started seeing the issue you describe.

Our client was scheduled for their Dynamics 365 version 9 (`9.0.2.449`) update last night. Today, their documents are being generated by the workflow successfully.

Comment: Hi Gina

Really ? I guessed it but not sure. In your scenario, generating the document was in same way as in my scenario ?
And you know when I generate template manually from  ribbon button (OOB feature) then there is no issue.
Although I am following up with Microsoft, will update here once I get some update.
Thanks.

Comment: To confirm, we've (first) noticed this on an 8.2.2.2060 environment also.

Comment: Hhhmm... It means this is CRM update issue.
Our CRM's upgrade plan is not near by, till then we have to continue with this issue :(

Comment: Did not get any update from MICROSOFT Support team, they are still looking into it, current version is 8.2.2.2114 and issue is still happening. Will keep posted for all.